# mysql copy data between two servers (localhost) different ports

Tags: mysql

I have set up two mysql servers on localhost that listen on two different ports.

server_A: 3306 and serverB: 3307

I need to copy the data from  server_A to  server_B,

**but in server_B I need to change the database names, tables names  and columns names**

Before starting to do tests I would like if someone knows if FEDERATED could be used for this case,  or what other would be more appropriate to do this ?

Comment: do you want to setup replication or just a one-time export-import job?

Comment: Yes is some like a replication (data) but change only names ... and after that ... once the name has been changed, from then on I will only check if there are changes between the two

Comment: To check the changes then I will use PHP  filemtime() for the * .frm files of each table + a TIMESTAMP column inside. This would not be a problem. I also have to say that this is only for developement so not security cares

Comment: Could you not just just replicate the identical table and then have a view on server_B with the different table and column names looking at the original database?

Comment: No. I really have to change the names. I am now with a working around about this. in some steps: 1 I make one mysqldump (separate files structure and delimited-text ) 2. with PHP preg_replace_callback I change names in structure files (that not ambiguous I have all names prefixed )
3 Restore it in server_B
That if not exist in server_B ... If exist , I check  if .frm file in server_B is older to server_A ... if is older i check with a timestamp column only the last changes. Al that in one php script

Answer (score 0):

For copying between servers I usually recommend MySQLDBCopy from the MySQL Utilities.  But all those changes of names makes it impossible.  If you could get away if not renaming the columns, you could use it.

Comment: Thank's ... but Not ... I need change the names